# Make IB 3.2.6 more verbose while installing plug-in

Tags: xcode, plugins, interface-builder

I have rewritten IB 2x palette to IB 3x plug-in, but I can't load it via IB Preferences.
IB shows message: "The bundle CLControlsIBPlugin couldn't be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle". And I couldn't see any error or warning messages from IB or XCode in console.app.
But when I launched IB via XCode debugger, both Debug and Release versions of plug-in were loaded successfully.

My plug-in CLControlsIBPlugin.ibplugin is a wrapper for CLControls.framework and therefore depends on CLControls.framework, CLKeymapper.framework, CLCommon.framework and CLKeymapper.framework depends on libKeymapTables.dylib, CLCommon.framework.

I've copied all these dependencies to plug-in's Contents/Frameworks folder in "Copy files" build phase and also made make symbolic links to them at ~/Library/Frameworks and /Library/Frameworks.

How to make IB more verbose?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by changing $(INSTALL_PATH) of all dependencies to $(USER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks, rebuilding them and then copying to ~/Library/Frameworks. I'm confused, because as far as I know, system **must** check

/Library/Frameworks,

/Network/Library/Frameworks,

/System/Library/Frameworks